# What is the point of declaring variables like this in Node.JS

Tags: node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltf1J.png)

What is the purpose of the curly brackets around the id and bio variables. I am relatively new to node.js and don't understand why you would want to declare them this way, instead of declaring them like:

const id = req.params;
const bio = req.body;

Comment: [Please post text, not links to images of text :)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) See the [MDN Object Destructuring docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring).

Answer (score 1):

This is called destructuring. You can find the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Is useful because you can make assignments in less lines, for example

```
const metadata = {
  title: 'Scratchpad',
  translations: [
    {
      locale: 'de',
      localization_tags: [],
      last_edit: '2014-04-14T08:43:37',
      url: '/de/docs/Tools/Scratchpad',
      title: 'JavaScript-Umgebung'
    }
  ],
  url: '/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad'
};
```

You could assign variables like:

```
const title = metadata.title;
const translations = metadata.translations;
const url = metadata.url;
```

Or using destructuring:

```
const {title, translations, url} = metadata;
```

So, using destructuring is easier and recommended in a lot of cases

Comment: Thank You, This helped me. So declaring const {id} = req.params is actually saying id = req.params.id